# Is it possible to store Binary Data in TempData?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I'm wondering.  If I have a form that is broken up into steps where I allow users to upload various files, can I keep those files in TempData as binary data?

I need to be able to Save the file to disk, as well as save it to a database.

I have a single index.cshtml for a ViewModel  that on each post, displays an editor for a property of the ViewModel that is of type `IStepViewModel`  So each step represents a portion of the total data to be collected.

This way I can have 1 index.cshtml page to manage, and as many steps as I want.

The client wants some steps to allow uploads, and others won't.  They also want the uploads to be Ajaxy, which means posting while a step may be incomplete.

I want to be able to on the last review step, let them know here are the files you are thinking about uploading...Until they click the final `TRANSMIT`  the files are in TempData,  This way I think I can have a single atomic operation.

The operation would
 - Save all the form data once again to DB
 - Mark the database record with a bit flag of `transmitted`
 - Save the files onto our server

Maybe there is a completely different approach I should be taking...If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TempData uses session store to store data, thus anything that can be serialized can be saved there.

However, in your case, saving files in session store is probably not a good idea as you can easily run out of memory.

A solution would be used a tempfile based storage (you can even implement a [temp db/file based session store](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/414/storing-uploaded-files-in-a-database-or-in-the-file-system-with-aspnet-20).

- As a user uploads the files, the files are written to a temp folder on a server (it could be a centralized one if your application is web farm based).
- A pointer to the temp folder is stored in TempData.
- Once the wizard process completes successfully, these files can be moved to DB and permanent fileserver.
- Your app can decide to purge the temp files or a nightly job can purge those files.

This would avoid multiple trips to DB and unnecesary I/O on DB.

You can also make [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) as the backing store of your session or some other DB ([oracle](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HarishsCustomSessionStore.aspx)) that persists temp data. This way, your app deals with TempData and is agnostic of how the temp files are stored.

Comment: I accepted your answer since you provided the information to direct me towards a solution that I may implement.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'm currently doing something similar myself (not storing files but implementing my own provider to go against the custom session server that the client has).

Answer (score 1):

`TempData` gets stored in the session<strike>, but only until the next request</strike>, so there is a high probability of losing anything you store there. This is not the way it was intended to be used.

From your user's perspective, atomicity of their operations is not *nearly* as important as an assurance that their data will not be lost unexpectedly. As a user, I *hate* it when I have to go look up a bunch of information to finish filling out a form, and then find out that my session timed out before I clicked "finish."

I'd suggest you model the progress the user is making in your data store (probably a combination of database and file store in this case). Let the user upload files, and have the files saved to a specific place. Make the database have a model that represents the various form data they are filling out, with references to the files that the user has uploaded. When the user finishes the final step, you can mark the wizard "complete" in your database, which sort of finalizes everything that's been done so far.

You could decide whether you want users to be able to "continue" the wizard after they have been inactive for a certain amount of time, or whether you'd prefer to have a policy that any wizards that are incomplete after the user's session ends are free to be expunged.

#### Update

I didn't realize that the behavior of `TempData` had changed, but items now persist there until they are read out of `TempData`, or until the session expires. This makes the data slightly less volatile than before, but it is still a dangerous place to keep data that your users have taken time out of their day to enter and upload.

Comment: From Microsoft's site: "This behavior is new in ASP.NET MVC 2. In earlier versions of ASP.NET MVC, the values in TempData was available only until the next request."

Comment: @Doug: Thanks for pointing that out. The principle remains, though. I can think of a number of things that could easily cause the user's data to be lost part-way through the wizard. Besides that, it's generally bad practice to keep large amounts of data on the session, and allowing the users to upload entire files into their session is just asking to run out of memory space real quick.

Comment: Thanks for your updates to correct some of the outdated information.